# Was the Saturn V ever stacked anywhere other than KSC?

Tags: saturn-v, museum-exhibits

I’ve always thought that the only place you could have ever seen a full Saturn V standing upright was the Kennedy Space Center. Is this true, or has the Saturn V ever been stacked vertically at any other location?

For example, I have heard about the [Saturn V Dynamic Test Stand](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V_dynamic_test_stand), but I wasn’t sure if the full stack was ever assembled and tested there. I’m also not sure if the rocket has ever been displayed at any other museum or rocket garden in a vertical configuration.

Comment: There's a full size fake one in the vertical at the US Space & Rocket Center in Huntsville. The one in the dynamic test stand was a full stack (not a real Apollo spacecraft though), but a ground test article only. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V_dynamic_test_vehicle

Comment: I think it was very unlikely that a Saturn V was transported as separate stages to another place, stacked there, disassembled later, transported to KSC, stacked again and launched from KSC. The reliability would be lower due to the additional transports and manipulations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on to what degree you define the [SA-500D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V_dynamic_test_vehicle) as "a full Saturn V".

All components of it where certainly stacked vertically at the [Saturn V Dynamic Test Stand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V_dynamic_test_stand), as can be seen in the 1966 Wikimedia photo below. (also includes a simple Apollo mockup).

"Full stack" was called ["Configuration I"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIJ-fNSNYXY)

The only test article of the SA-500D to be launched into space was the [LTA-2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:67-H-1230_Lunar_module_LTA-2_R.jpg) on Apollo 4.

Most of the other components of the SA-500D are currently displayed at the US Space & Rocket Center in Huntsville (but not vertically). If you consider this a "fake" one, the Saturn V dynamic test vehicle is also fake, as they are essentially the same components.

[image: SA-500D]

Comment: The SA-500D is displayed horizontally inside at Huntsville. The outside vertically displayed one is 100% fake.

Comment: Fails the "vertical" part then.

Comment: https://www.rocketcenter.com/saturn-v-hall https://www.rocketcenter.com/rocket-park

Comment: hey, ive been to huntsville and seen that, really cool place